# Compare $L^1$ and $L^2$ metrics on $C[0 ,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

$d_2$ = $\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}|f(x) - g(x)|^2}$ is a metric on $C[0 ,1]$ and  $d_1 =\int_{0}^{1}|f(x) - g(x)|$.

Now let's consider two metric spaces one is $X_1$ = $(X, d_1)$ and another one is $X_2$ = $(X, d_2)$ where $X = C[0 , 1]$
Now my question is whether $X_1$ and $X_2$ are homeomorphic or not. I know $d_1$ and $d_2$ have to be equivalent. But how can I prove or disprove. Can anyone help me out to find whether identity functions, one from $X_1$ to $X_2$ and another from $X_2$ to $X_1$ are continuous or not.
Thank You

Comment: May be Cauchy Schwarz inequality should help you get the equivalence you are looking for

Comment: What is $X?\,\,$

Comment: how?? Can u plzz elaborate?@S.C

Comment: Why do you say "I know $d_1$ and $d_2$ have to be equivalent."?

Comment: I meant $d_1$ and $d_2$ have to be equivalent to be homeomorhism

Comment: That's false for general homeomorphisms

Comment: how can u plzz explain? @zhw

Comment: $\mathbb R$ with its usual metric, and $\mathbb R$ with the metric $d(a,b) = |a-b|/(1+|a-b|).$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59940/discussion-between-cmi-and-zhw).

Comment: I don't do chat, sorry.

Comment: okk..so what happened? they are equivalent and id maps are continuous..Are not they?


????????????


where r u?? I am too curious to know.. I may have a big misconception...

Comment: They are homeomorphic, but not using the identity map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $d_2$ metric comes from the inner product
$$
\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) \overline{ g(x)} dx.
$$

So you can apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to
$$
\int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert dx = \langle \lvert f \rvert, \chi_{[0,1]} \rangle,
$$
to find the first inequality.

But do you think another inequality $\lVert f \rVert_2 \leq \alpha \lVert f \rVert_1$ will hold for some $\alpha> 0$? Consider for example
$$
f_n = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0 & \text{ if } x > 1/n^2 \\
n-xn^3 & \text{ if } x \leq 1/n^2 \end{matrix}\right.
$$
Will this converge to zero in both topologies?

Comment: WHAT IS first inequality? Can u plzzz elaborate little bit.. It is so short for a first reader..@Demophilus

Comment: I thought I already was being very elaborate. Simply apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $\langle \lvert f \rvert, \chi_{[0,1]} \rangle$ and you will find it.

Comment: Can u plzz clearly mention how the identity map from $X_2$ to $X_1$ is not continuous.......

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n(x) = \sqrt n x^n.$ Then $f_n \to 0$ in $(X,d_1)$ but not in $(X,d_2).$

Comment: So there does not exist any continuous function from $X_1$ to $X_2$...what about $X_2$ to $X_1$ @zhw

Comment: @cmi Of course there exists a continuous function from $X_2$ to $X_1.$ A constant function for example.

Comment: sorry...@Demophilus 'S last example prove that  identity map from $X_2$ to $X_1$ is not continuous.... Am I wrong?

Comment: No, the identity going from $X_2$ to $X_1$ is t continuous. My example above shows the identity going from $X_1$ to $X_2$ is not continuous.

Comment: t continuous??@zhw

Comment: The t was a typo. Pretend it's not there.

Comment: $$
f_n = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0 & \text{ if } x > 1/n^2 \\
n-xn^3 & \text{ if } x \leq 1/n^2 \end{matrix}\right.$$ take this sequence...then it will converge in$X_2$ but not in $X_1$..Is not it?

Comment: I'm done here. I've given you a very simple example. If you have questions on the answer of @Demophilus, then you should ask Demophilus.

Comment: no no u did not tell me why the identity map from $X_2$ to $X_1$  not continuous?